# Audit JDBC execute on JBossAS5

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, driver

I use JBossAS5 and JDBC to connect database and want to log all JDBC executed SQL.
The data source is configured to JNDI resource in '-ds.xml' as JBossAS required.
I don't want to use DBMS itself to log SQL. In addition, the log operation should be transparent to business logic.

My approach: I wrote a proxy Driver class which implements `java.sql.Driver` and delegates the real driver class underlying. Then the proxy Driver is registered in -ds.xml.
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) seems to be the current best-of-breed for this sort of thing, although I haven't tried it with JBoss's datasource descriptors yet.

Give it a try.

You really don't want to implement this yourself, though. There are a LOT of interfaces in JDBC that you'd need to implement.

Comment: Thanks! 
log4jdbc seems also a Driver proxy, I'll make a try.